# Call gevent.sleep with timeout

Tags: python, gevent, event-loop

I would essentially like `gevent.sleep` to behave like `time.sleep` in that it returns execution after *exactly* (not *at least*) some number of seconds, but allow other Greenlets to run in the meantime.

An example:

```
import gevent
def a():
    while True:
        print "A"
        gevent.sleep(0.2)
def b():
    gevent.spawn(a)
    while True:
        print "B"
        gevent.sleep(1)
b()
# often get more than 10 or 20 'A's for each 'B', would expect close to 5
```

Is there a better way to get the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine. I ran it on my linux machine and had this output:

B
A
A
A
A
A
B
A
A
A
A
A
B
A
A
A
A
A
B
A
A
A
A
A
B
A
A
A
A
A
B
A
A
A
A
A

So it works very reliably on my end, running gevent 1.0.1 and python2.7.
If it does not work on your end, you might want to try and update python or gevent.

Comment: Running python 2.7.11 and gevent 1.0.2. Interesting, after restarting python I get the correct output the first time but the problem I described after subsequent calls.

Comment: Ahh it had to do with forgetting to kill the Greenlet running `a` upon `KeyboardInterrupt`